# Google Sheet, editable cells vary by person

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way for me to assign which cells can be access by each user?
I have google sheet I use for budget- cells B5:J30 is for requester and cells K5:L30 is for approver.

Thanks!

Jaja

Answer (score 0):

Under Data there is an option called "protect sheets and ranges" which can restrict a certain group of cells on the spreadsheet to specific users, allowing only specific people to edit a certain range. Multiple restriction can be made on a single spreadsheet, and you can restrict them to more than just yourself. I am uncertain if the creator of the spreadsheet is the only person with permission to create new restrictions.